# shared memory multi-threading and data accessing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, caching

Regarding performance, assuming we get a block of data that will be freqenctly accessed by each threads, and these data are read-only, which means threads wont do anything besides reading the data.

Then is it benefitial to create one copy of these data (assuming the data there read-only) for each thread or not?

If the freqenently accessed data are shared by all threads (instead of one copy for each thread), wouldnt this increase the chance of these data will get properly cached?

Comment: 1. regarding creating one copy yes it is good strategy 
2. if frequently accessed data are shared by all threads, it wont help with caching

Comment: If the data is trully read-only then it would be properly cached, even if shared. If the data is being modified, the cache coherency protocol would kick in. Watch out for false sharing, i.e. writing to data that falls in the same cache line as the shared read-only portion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One copy of read-only data *per thread* will not help you with caching; quite the opposite, it can hurt instead when threads execute on the same multicore (and possibly hyperthreaded) CPU and so share its cache, as in this case per-thread copies of the data may compete for limited cache space.

However, in case of a multi-CPU system, virtually all of which are NUMA nowadays, typically having per-CPU memory banks with access cost somewhat different between the "local" and "remote" memory, it can be beneficial to have a *per-CPU* copies of read-only data, placed in its local memory bank.

The memory mapping is controlled by OS, so if you take this road it makes sense to study NUMA-related behavior of your OS. For example, Linux uses first-touch memory allocation policy, which means memory mapping happens not at `malloc` but when the program accesses a memory page for the first time, and OS tries to allocate physical memory from the local bank.

And the usual performance motto applies: measure, don't guess.

Comment: Nice answer, I especially like the last part: "Measure dont guess".

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tested the algorithm (it takes quite a bit time to get a proper non-trivial test), actually it seems that the one-copy-one-thread method is actually faster than the one-copy-shared-by-all-threads approach, at least that is for my cases, one CPU and multi-cores.